# Combinatorics question about creating a group from $3$ different groups

Tags: combinatorics

> Group $A$ has $3$ persons,  Group $B$ has $5$ persons,  Group $C$ has $4$ persons.
>   With how many different combinations you can create a new group which
>   has one person from each of the groups$(A,B,C)?$ (one from $A$,one from
>   $B$,one from $C$)

I tried $ \dbinom {3}{1} \cdot \dbinom {5}{1} \cdot \dbinom {4}{1} $. 
Why? I'm thinking that each position in the new group is reserved to one of the $3$ groups. 
Am I right?
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this is right; you can think of this as an application of the Multiplication Principle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, $\binom31\binom51\binom41$ is right. Or you could simply have said that there are $3$ ways to pick a person from Group A, $5$ ways to pick one from Group B, and $4$ ways to pick one from Group C, for a total of $3\cdot5\cdot4$ ways to pick the group of three (by the [multiplication principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product)).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that looks fine to me. Now, $ \dbinom {n}{1} = n $, so you can multiply quite easily.